# Why not to use splice with spread operator to remove item from an array in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, immutability

[splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates the original array and should be avoided. Instead, one good option is to use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which creates a new array so does not mutates the state. But I used to remove items from an array using splice() with spread operator.

```
removeItem = index => {
  const items = [...this.state.items];
  items.splice(index, 1);

  this.setState({ items });
}
```

So in this case when I log `items` changes but `this.state.items` stays unchanged. 
Question is, why does everyone use `filter` instead of `splice` with `spread`? Does it have any cons?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Comment: works just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-euclid-hnove

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` has a more functional approach, which has its benefits. Working with immutable data is much more easier, concurrency and error safe.

But in your example, you are doing something similar by creating the `items` array. So you are still not mutating any existing arrays.

---

```
const items = [...this.state.items];
```

Creates a copy of `this.state.items`, thus it will not mutate them once you do a `splice()`.

So considering you approach, it is no different than `filter()`, so now it just boils down to a matter of taste.

```
const items = [...this.state.items];
items.splice(index, 1);
```

**VS**

```
this.state.items.filter(i => ...);
```

Also performance may be taken into consideration. Check this [test](https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-filter) for example.

Comment: Check this test too please https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/814/0/remove-by-splice-vs-copywithin-vs-filter

Comment: Yes, depends on what is your environment, your tests and so on. But I wouldn't worry about this as it runs in the browser. If it was a server call which handles hundreds of requests per second, then I would consider performance a priority, otherwise not. Use most maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const items = [...this.state.items]; // spread
 const mutatedItems = this.state.items.filter(() => {}) // filter
```

they are the same.
although i found spread line is confusing, and less intuitive than filter.

but i prefer destructuring:

```
 const { items } = this.state // destructure
 item.splice()
```

why? because sometimes within a function/method i have other destructuring assignment such

```
  const { modalVisible, user } = this.state
```

So i think why not destructure `item` as well there.
For some who writes a lot of codes in multiple codebase, it would help a lot to work on on "how accurate, and fast can this code skimmed?" as i myself dont really remember what i wrote last week.
While using spread would make me write more lines and doesnt help me when re-read it next month.

Comment: in your example you are changing `state` without going through `setState()`

Comment: But this method mutates this.state

Comment: destructuring would still maintain the same reference to `items` and mutate when you change `items`

Comment: Oh im sorry i thought it would maintain reference only if its an object.